# How to figure out if two linear functions are, after being rounded, equal over a given range

Tags: math, optimization

Title is a bit confusing and uses mathy words, so just take a look at this C function:

```
void myfun(uint stepcount,float step,float base,int *step_array) {
    for (uint i=0;i<stepcount;i++) {
        base += step;
        step_array[i] = (int)floor(base);
    }
}
```

**Given `stepcount` and `step` (always between 0 and 1), how can I tell if two `base` values will write the same results into `step_array`?**

Comment: Are you looking for something beyond brute force (evaluating the values and comparing)?

Comment: Yes. (the intent is being able to skip evaluation of "adjacent" base values that amount to the same result)

(Altough I actually didn't even think of brute forcing it, that may actually work out...(the same set of base values is eval'd multiple times))